# How to Show Javascript Modal Boxes Without Button?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a script to open modal boxes with javascript when user click the button, but i want to modify the script, to show the modal boxes when page is loaded with the specific parameter. 
Example : http://domain.com/login?msg=incorrect password

Any solution ?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the demo of my code : http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
});
```

What this will do is:

- An event will happen, when the DOM Content has been loaded.
- When that happens, it will fire the function that you've just defined
- Your modal is now shown when automatically

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer, i got a bit. but can you give me a bit solution from this : i have modified my question a bit.

but i want to modify the script, to show the modal boxes when page is loaded with the specific parameter. 
Example : http://domain.com/login?msg=incorrect password

Comment: i try to add 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
});
to my js. but didnt show automatically.

Comment: I've tried it on your example, and it did work for me (did you add it inside the `script` tags, and after `modal` has been defined?). Regarding the url, you could use `window.location.search === '?msg=incorrect'` to find if the parameter is there or not.

Comment: hello sir,  can you try on it? http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2
and press open modal. i want the modal will load in page with ?msg=incorrect password parameter. I'm very sorry but i am very newbie in javascript. so i need a very specific tutorial. thank you before